# How to hide or make it visible based on the condition given in the TextChanged event of the Textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, textbox, textchanged

I am having a textbox on my web form. Within this textbox I am using Jquery Auto Complete. I have taken two labels on my web form and trying to hide this label based on the condition I have given in the TextChanged event of the Textbox. But I am not able display the visible one.
This is my aspx page-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
      var items=[<%=autotag %>];
      $("#TextBox1").autocomplete({
      source:items
      });
      });
  </script>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Name:</td>
<td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ontextchanged="TextBox1_TextChanged1" 
        AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox></td>
</tr>
   <tr><td colspan="2">
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Visible="False">
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></asp:Panel>
    </td></tr>
</table>
```

My cs page-

```
public string autotag="";
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack == false)
    {
        bind1();
    }
}
```

//This bind1() is for autocomplete.

```
public void bind1()
{
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString);
con.Open();
string query="select name from tbl_data_show";
SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand(query,con);
SqlDataReader dr=cmd.ExecuteReader();
dr.Read();
while(dr.Read())
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(autotag))
    {
        autotag+="\""+dr["name"].ToString()+"\"";
    }
    else
    {
        autotag+=", \""+dr["name"].ToString()+"\"";
    }
}
}
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString);
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select name from tbl_data_show where name='"+TextBox1.Text+"'", con);
    //DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
    //SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    //da.Fill(dt1);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.HasRows)
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            Panel1.Visible = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Panel1.Visible = false;
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

Please guide me where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to get something to happen on the client with c# code.  You have to use javascript.

Comment: where are you setting Lablel1.Visible = False; ?

Comment: @Dan Bracuk: Yes I want that if the user will not select names from the suggestion given by the auto complete, then the Label will be hidden otherwise Label will be visible. How can I use javascript for this? Please help me with some example.

Comment: @anbuj: Actually I have kept both the labels visibility false. I forgot to mention it in my code.

Comment: @Omi Have you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If am not wrong, please try by setting autopostback = true, change your asp tag line like this,

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ontextchanged="TextBox1_TextChanged1" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
```

**Update**

Try your coding in this way,

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack == false)
    {     
      bind1();
      //Panel1.Visible = true;
    }
}

 protected void TextBox1_TextChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString);
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select name from tbl_data_show where name='"+TextBox1.Text+"'", con);
   // DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
   // SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
   // da.Fill(dt1);
   SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
   if (dr.HasRows)
   {
       while (dr.Read())
       {
           Panel1.Visible = true;
           //if (dt1.Rows.Count > 0)
           //{
           //    if (TextBox1.Text == dr.GetString(0))
           //    {
           //        //Label1.Text = "4";
           //        //Label2.Text = "5";
           //        Panel1.Visible=true;
           //        //Label1.Visible = true;
           //        //Label2.Visible = false;
           //    }
           //    else
           //    {
           //        //Label2.Text = "5";
           //        Panel1.Visible = false;
           //        //Label2.Visible = true;
           //        //Label1.Visible = false;
           //    }
           //}
       }
   }
   else
   {
       Panel1.Visible = false;
   }
    con.Close();
}
```

Let me know, if you get struggle with this again.

**Autocomplete Using Ajax :**

Initially download ajaxcontrolkit from this [link](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/116091), and then add into your project using this [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/yousefjadallah/archive/2010/04/16/installing-ajax-control-toolkit-4-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx) and then add this line into your source page (below to <%@ page>)

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
```

**aspx :**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ontextchanged="TextBox1_TextChanged1" 
    AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
     <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            </asp:ScriptManager>
              <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ServiceMethod="SearchCustomers" 
MinimumPrefixLength="1"
CompletionInterval="100" EnableCaching="false" CompletionSetCount="10" 
TargetControlID="TextBox1"
ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" FirstRowSelected = "false">
```

**Code Behind :**

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //bind1();
}
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static List<string> SearchCustomers(string prefixText, int count)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
    {
        conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager
                .ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "select name from tbl_data_show where " +
            "name like @SearchText + '%'";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefixText);
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            List<string> customers = new List<string>();
            using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    customers.Add(sdr["name"].ToString());
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
            return customers;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting all the names in the suggestion but the panel visibility is working only when I am giving Sagar as my input.

Comment: Ok I will try and let you know for sure.
Thanks a lot Gk you helped me a lot. I guess we are almost near to the solution of this problem.

Comment: If possible, try and let me know the result.

Comment: Sorry change like this, if(TextBox1.Text == dr["name"])

Comment: Hello rishy, I have also tried by matching the text with dr["name"], but still the panel is not visible on text changed event fire.

Comment: Try by removing that if(ispostback) event in page load.

Comment: No effect. Still the panel is not visible

Comment: Could you tell me your database structure(with datatype and table name)?

Comment: Table name is- tbl_data_show
database structure- id int not null, name varchar(50) not null
Data in the table are- Ashish,Joy,Abhishek,Abir, Shashi, Sagar

Comment: Are you there ?. Check my updated answer. I worked here and tested. It works fine, so please follow this. It may get out of from our huge struggle.

Comment: Yes make it visible false in panel's property.

Comment: still the panel is not visible :-(
I am very confused what is happening with it. Rishy I am updating my codes. You please check my question. also check the aspx code as well.

Comment: Plz check my updated code in my question. And plz guide me where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Yeah am checking, don't worry. Will do the best. Try changing varchar(50) to nvarchar(50) in table design...and let me know.

Comment: If you are not comfortable to change in table, change here itself like this, select name from tbl_data_show where cast(name as nvarchar)='"+TextBox1.Text+"'" (Am not sure in this method, just try and let me know)

Comment: No still the panel is not visible on textchange event.
But I have checked in database by by using this query "SELECT     name
FROM         tbl_data_show
WHERE     (CAST(name AS nvarchar) = 'Ashish')"
and it is giving me the result also I am getting two rows, 1 is for Ashish and the other one is the Null data.

Comment: If you use the above query, don't change in table structure. If you changed in table, don't use the cast() in query.

Comment: Yes I have not changed the table structure. But still the panel is not visible.

Comment: Try with changing table design(varchar(50) to nvarchar(50)). Don't use that cast() method which i mentioned in query.

Comment: Oh I am extremely sorry Gk. Actually I was not giving text in the label that is why I was not able to understand whether the panel was visible or not. Finally it is working the panel is visible when text is matching. and hidden when not. Your effort was really appreciable. I am really thankful to you buddy. But I only one doubt if you can clear it.

Comment: oh.. When i worked here i noticed that problem(Label is in empty), but i forgot to say you and sure tell me.

Comment: As you know I am using jquery autocomplete in my textbox, but there is a problem, Since I have Ashish as my first record and I am fetching data from table, so according to my code Ashish should also display in the suggestion. right!
But Ashish is not displaying within the suggestion. Why can you please clear it?

Comment: Is it possible for you to use ajax control toolkit ?

Comment: Actually I wanted to learn it by using jquery that is why I have not used Ajax Controls.

Comment: This is the only problem I am facing now. I am taking this public string autotag to get the names stored in dr. I am getting all the names except the first record i.e "Ashish"

Comment: Check my updated part. Sorry i have posted before 10 minutes itself. But i forgot to inform you because of my work pressure.

Comment: Oh its perfectly all right friend. I understand. Ok so you have done using web services. Great another interesting stuff. Ok I will try and let u know. Cheers :-)

Comment: Its not working GK. I tried exactly what you suggested. Autocomplete is not working.

Comment: did you changed connection string ?

Comment: Did you removed your old javascript  ?

Comment: What happened ?, any updates ?. Try by removing your old java script, it will you give the desired output by including "Ashish".

Comment: Okies. If I only want to use autocomplete in the textbox then there is no need to set autpostback to true. Right?

Comment: Yes, if you want only autocomplete with textbox then no need of considering autopostback. Make it as false.

Comment: I have taken a new textbox and used ajax autocompleteextender, still its not working.

Comment: Did you changed the TargetControlID in auto complete extender ?

Comment: Yes I did. I have taken this on a new web form.

Comment: See this-
`<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="TextBox1_AutoCompleteExtender" runat="server" 
            CompletionInterval="100" EnableCaching="False" MinimumPrefixLength="1" 
            ServiceMethod="searchtag" TargetControlID="TextBox1">
        </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>`

Comment: Have you changed to searchtag in code behind, instead of searchcustomer ? and check whether you have CompletionSetCount="10"  and FirstRowSelected = "false".

Comment: Still you are not getting first record ?, here am getting all the records with above query. If possible show your code behind for autocomplete.

Comment: No actually this time. I am not even getting single record. Autocomplete extender I guess is not working.

Comment: Show your code behind ?, it might be a small mistake.

Comment: `public static List<string> searchtag(string prefixText, int count)
{using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection()){con.ConnectionString =ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
{cmd.CommandText = "select name from tbl_names where" + "name like @searchText + '%'";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchText", prefixText);
cmd.Connection = con;con.Open();
List<string> tags = new List<string>();
using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{while (dr.Read())
{tags.Add(dr["name"].ToString());}}
con.Close();return tags;}}}`

Comment: Sorry about the alignment of my cs code. Actually it was not taking since the characters were too long.

Comment: No issues. Did you mentioned these lines    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
as i mentioned in my updated part ?

Comment: Yes I mentioned it in my code. But due to character length factors I had not posted here.

Answer (score 1):

if you are not setting Lable visibility false anywhere else, try this

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dt = g1.return_dt("select name from tbl_data_show");
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        if (TextBox1.Text == dt.Rows[0]["name"])
        {
            Label1.Text = "4";
            Label1.Visible = true;
        }

        else if (TextBox1.Text != dt.Rows[0]["name"])
        {
            Label2.Text = "5";
            Label2.Visible = true;
        }
        else
         {
           Label1.Visible = false;
           Label2.Visible = false;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you are keeping Lable.Visible = false; somewhere it is triggered on postback, it may change back to invisible. Please put a break point and debug step by step. Please confirm that your pointer hits the code inside the if clause and after that not hitting your Lable.Visible = false; line..

Comment: I have kept both the labels visibility false. And in my code I am checking if the text entered in the textbox matches with the database record then label1 will get vsisible, and if not then label2 will get visible. This is what I am doing.